# Cloning environment with micromamba

Tags: conda, mamba

It seems micromamba is missing a **clone environment option**, or is it just named differently?

- Mamba's help `micromamba create -n envname --help`
  does not seem to show any clone-like option and

- standard conda's
  `conda create -n envname --clone oldenv` doesn't seem to work.

If mamba is missing clone option, what is the reason for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yeah, It does not have a cloning option yet**

#### Minor Update

the command to create the environment failed with micromamba `version 1.4.9`, use the `--file` flag,

```
micromamba env create --name newenv --file oldenv.yaml
```

-- [informed by gkaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11254060/gkaf)

### REASON:

It's simply because it is designed as a lightweight, fast, and minimal version of `mamba`. The clone environment is a relatively complex feature, and it was not considered to be essential for the core functionality of `micromamba`.

### SOLUTION:

There is a roundabout way although. As per I know, you can export the current env as `yaml` and run `micromamba env create` to create a env from the yaml file.

#### Export the contents of the existing environment to a YAML file.

```
micromamba env export -n oldenv > oldenv.yaml
```

#### Create a new environment from the YAML file.

```
micromamba env create -n newenv -f oldenv.yaml
```

This should work, notify if it doesn't.

Comment: Minor update: the command to create the environment failed with micromamba version 1.4.9, use the `--file` flag, `micromamba env create --name newenv --file oldenv.yaml`.

Comment: When I run `micromamba env export jax-cuda > jax-cuda.yaml` I get the error `The following argument was not expected: jax-cuda`

Comment: What if you try this `micromamba env export > jax-cuda.yaml` in the old env

Comment: @Tom original post was missing the `-n` or `--name` flag: `micromamba env export -n jax-cuda > jax-cuda.yaml`

Comment: Does this route use hardlinks, so as not to explode disk usage?

Comment: @HindSagarBiswas I tried the command but am getting this error

micromamba env create -n me7953 --file base.yaml 
```critical libmamba Invalid spec file. Aborting```